# Android problems binding started service

Tags: android, android-service

I start my service in onCreate() (if onCreate is called the first time) and call bindService in onStart(). The service probaply works, but after calling bindService my local instance of the service is still null. Furthermore, is seems to be that getService() is not called.?
Here is some code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
if(savedInstanceState == null){
   final Intent i = new Intent(this, HostService.class);
   startService(i);
}

}

protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    bindService(new Intent(this, StartGameActivity.class), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection(){

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
        HostBinder binder = (HostBinder) arg1;
        hostService = binder.getService();
        isBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        isBound = false;
    }

};
```

and in HostService:

```
...
private HostBinder binder = new HostBinder();
...
public class HostBinder extends Binder{
    HostService getService(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getService");
        return HostService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return binder;
}
```

Why is hostService still null, after onStart() is called and why is getService is not getting called ("getService" is not print in LogCat)?

thx & regards

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `startService()`; it will be started by `bindService()`.

In your `onStart()` method, you're creating an intent to launch **StartGameActivity.class**. Was that what you wanted, or did you mean to launch **HostService.class**?

If neither of those are your problem, we need more to go on. Can you put a logging statement inside your `onServiceConnected()` and `onBind()` methods so you can be sure they're called?

Any logcat messages that look interesting?

Are you talking to your service via the binder, or via messaging?

Comment: ahhhhw shit. Yes I meant HostService.class. Knocked me out for a few hours :d thx a lot :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but if I do, the issue is that it takes time for the service to respond to the bind request and the Android system doesn't want your onCreate() to hang around waiting. So the request is handled asynchronously, and your onServiceConnected() gets called some time later.